# There is a way to avoid to download Spa Bundle every request in a PWA

Tags: single-page-application, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

So I've a full CRM aplication made in Vue.js the bundle is about 3mb size, now I'm working in PWA features and I want to know if is possible to avoid user browser to download the app even if the user is online, loading it from cache like the way it works when it is offline. Something like:

1 - User enter in aplication:

2 - Service works check if it has cached and is in the last version.

3 - If aplication is cached and updated it loads the cache storage, else request a new bundle.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What you describe is possible.

You're describing what is called a CacheFirst strategy. SW goes to network only when the asset is not found from its caches.

Take a look at the Workbox docs here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies